# Keeping JavaScript file separate from webpack bundle

Tags: webpack

A web application I am deploying uses Webpack 4 to produce a Javascript bundle to be served to the browser. One of the Javascript files is `client_config.js`, which holds some options for my particular deployment.

I'd like Webpack to produce `main.bundle.js` *but* load `client_config.js` separately. This way I can edit the config file on the server without having to re-bundle everything.

I've followed the [Code Splitting guide](https://v4.webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) and created a separate entry point for `client_config.js`:

```js
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js',
    client_config: './src/client_config.js'
  },
```

Then I also enabled the optimization to split the chunks up:

```js
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
    },
  },
```

This produces now `main.bundle.js` and `client_config.bundle.js`. However, the `main.bundle.js` still includes the contents of `client_config.js`.

You can see this in [this example repository](https://github.com/rgov/webpack-test) that includes a bare minimum reproduction.

Comment: So you require/import some code from `client_config.js` in `main` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.